# How do I upload a file using an httphandler in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

How do I upload a file using an httphandler?

Comment: What aspect of usong an HttpHandler is causing trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this :

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/HttpHandlerFileUploader.aspx